# JavaScript onclick redirecting not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

[Here you can see my website and error](https://developerkaushal.engineer)

when I click on button my website is not redirecting to that link only website start reloading

```js
function send() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
  var message = document.getElementById('descriptions').value;

  if (name && email && message === '') {
    window.navigator.vibrate('200');

    alert('Enter something');
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'https://wa.me/919811192234/?text=' + 'Hy' +
      ' ' + 'I' + ' ' + 'Am' + ' ' + name + '                                                  ' + email.value + '                                              ' + message + '                   '
  }

  console.log(name && email && message)
}
```

```html
<div class="contactus" id="contact">
  <p align="center">CONTACT US</p>
  <hr width="50%" size="5px" color="aqua">

  <form action="" id="demo-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name*" id="name">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email*" id="mail">

    <textarea placeholder="Message For Us*" id="descriptions" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="submit1" onclick="send()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want that when user click on that button he will redirect to whatsapp

Comment: `name&&email&&message===''` is unlikely to be what you think it is.   From your code, and the parameters to the location.href, I would *guess* you want `name === '' || email === '' || message=== ''`

Comment: submit buttons submit

Comment: You may want to censor the phone number...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your button is submitting the form, what you can do is add a `onSubmit` handler on your form, which looks something like:

```html
<form onSubmit="send(event)">
</form>
```

and then in your javascript:

```js
function send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    .... do something here ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open(URL, "_blank") so that it will open that in a new tab and this will work.

> window.open("https://wa.me/919811192234/?text="+"Hy"+
> " "+"I"+" "+"Am"+" "+name+" ", "_blank");

Answer (score 0):

The button is (by default) `type="submit"`. Clicking the button will submit its form owner by default.

You are adding a `click` listener but don't prevent the click's default action of submitting its form owner.

This means *your redirection is being overriden* by the submission's action.

To prevent this you should **prevent the event's default action** by calling `event.preventDefault()`:

- Preventing the `click` event's default action prevents the following `submit` event from dispatching.
- Preventing the `submit` event's default action prevents the form's default action (i.e. 'redirection').

---

Since you handle submission logic, you should use a `submit` listener. Using a `submit` listener on the form over a `click` listener on the button comes with some benefits:

- Submission only happens once the form is valid (i.e. all required inputs are valid).
- It conveys intention better: We listen for a submission of the form, not simply a click on the button. Clicking the button is only a means of submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `<button>`'s `type` attribute from `submit` to `button` will give you desired behavior, because it won't fire `submit` event, this way default behavior(page reload) won't happen.